# Python compare data from CSV file with data from JSON don't work

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am new to Python and want to write a tool that retrieves products on an online platform via API and compares them to a CSV file. If the value in the file and on the online platform do not match, the product should be updated online via API.

I was actually able to successfully retrieve the values I need but I am failing to compare them. My API call returns a response in JSON format and I imported the CSV file with pandas.

Here I am printing the part numbers from the API call and the CSV to test them:

```
for i in getProducts():
    print (i['partNumber'])

for i in df.index:
    print (df['Artikelnummer'][i])
```

and i get this output:

```
1001
1000
1001
1000
```

So it looks like the CSV and the JSON response have the same values when I test them with `print`.
But when I try to compare them with `if`, it always looks like they are not the same values.

This always returns 'false'.

```
for product in getProducts():
    for i in df.index:
        if product['partNumber'] == df['Artikelnummer'][i]:
            print('True')
        else:
            print('False')
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check our their dtypes, for example one of them can be string and the other integer. The both of the cases will print the same output and compare them will give False.

```
api = '1001'
other = 1001
print(api)
print(other)
print(api == other)

print('\nAfter cast them to the same type:')
print(int(api) == int(other))
```

Output:

```
1001
1001
False

After cast them to the same type:
True
```

Try to convert them to the same dtype.